# Binding not building correctly

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am creating a binding for the first time. It is a binding for the `Millennial Media SDK`. The binding on the [Montouch Binding Project](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/8fcc382b1b1bb607f913b423aa4e6c6241fac708/MMSDK) is very out of date.

I have resolved all the errors in my project, but the dll that gets built is only `3kb`. Could someone take a look at my binding and tell me what I have done wrong and how to get it to build correctly? Im sure its something simple.

https://github.com/Deekor/Millennial-Media-Monotouch-Binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I sent you a pull request, somehow your binding project got corrupted so I just copy-pasted and improved it a bit

Here is the PR https://github.com/Deekor/Millennial-Media-Monotouch-Binding/pull/1

Hope this helps

Alex

---

## Update

Added new pull request fixing the missing 'libz' framework

https://github.com/Deekor/Millennial-Media-Monotouch-Binding/pull/2

Hope this helps

alex

Comment: Thanks. Ill take a look at it. Since this was my first binding, did I do it wrong? Or did the files just get corrupted?

Comment: Files got corrupted, the project was not compiling, somehow it did not detect the namespace, you did a great job with the binding I just added the Notifications, separated the enums into its own file and added the needed frameworks to linkwith file

Comment: Also added a more NET'ish way to some functios

Comment: Sorry I was on a mobile phone so I could not detail a little bit more. The features that I improved where [Notifications](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries#3.8.binding-notifications) and needed [Frameworks](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries/binding_types_reference_guide#5.1.linkwithattribute), hope this is indeed working for you.

Comment: Hey sorry I didn't have time to try it until now. It built fine, but when I went to use it in my project I get this error: `error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.`

Comment: @Deekor ok, did not see that was required on the documentation, anyways I added a new pull request, see my update

Comment: @Deekor That is really weird, can you tell me if this file exist in your computer `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/lib/libz.dylib`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31876/discussion-between-deekor-and-dalexsoto)